# Правильное название

Tags: php, html, цвета

Есть код, в котором цвет блока генерируется случайным образом.

```
function random_html_color()
        {
            return sprintf('#%02X%02X%02X', rand(230, 255), rand(230, 255), rand(230, 255));
        }
```

Неправильно же будет говорить, что RGB-цвет генерируется в диапазоне от 230 до 255? Ведь если так будет, то цветных блоков не будет, а лишь оттенки серого.
Как правильно сказать, что генерируется, как бы, каждый подцвет в этом диапазоне, например, только R или G (в контексте нужно про все 3)?

Comment: Вызов функции rand возвращает уникальное значение каждый раз (по идее). На практике данный код будет недостаточным т.к вызовы идут один за другим и значения врядли будут уникальными.

Comment: А вопрос то в чем? Как назвать чтоли?

Comment: Расскажите каким образом вы собираетесь с помощью этого кода сгенерировать каждый подцвет? Если rand будет возвращать всегда псевдослучайное значение, это значит что на миллион вызовов этой функции он может вернуть как случайный набор значений RGB из диапазона так и все время один и тот же набор значений. Опишите задачу корректно, чего вы хотите добиться, можете добавить приблизительный результат как оно должно выглядеть.

Comment: Я имею в виду как правильно назвать каждый отдельный цвет из RGB, именно R, G и B. Мне нужно написать примерно так: "RGB-цвет генерируется случайным образом отдельно для каждой(-ого) ... ".